# Integer lattice points on a hypersphere

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, geometry

Is the following statement true?

> For every integer $n\ge2$ and every integer $k\ge0$ there exists a hypersphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$  (circle, sphere etc) containing exactly $k$ integer lattice points on its surface.

Comment: $k$ has to be even, since if $x$ is an integer point on the sphere, $-x$ is as well. 

Comment: @Ryan, the sphere need not have its center in the origin..

Comment: Ryan, not if the sphere is not centered at the origin. Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.05.21

Comment: Note that if it is true for n=2, then it is true for all n, by using a hypersphere of well chosen irrational radius with all the lattice points sitting in a two dimensional subspace.  Gerhard "Irrational Solutions To Rational Problems"  Paseman, 2013.05.21

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but is it true that the problem is open if the $k$ lattice points are *inside* the hypersphere?

Comment: Joel Reyes Noche: For each pair of lattice points there is a midpoint. Now choose a center c for the sphere that is not one of these (countably many) midpoints. As the radius is slowly increased from 0, the sphere will contain only one additional lattice point at a time. So any number of points is achieved with a certain range of radii.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several related and very interesting problems and theorems:

- [Schinzel's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchinzelsTheorem.html) - solves the problem in $\mathbb{R}^2$ using so-called [Schinzel circles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchinzelCircle.html). It seems intuitively clear that it generalizes to higher dimensions by slightly adjusting radius of a hypersphere so that it contains exactly the same lattice points as its section in lower dimension, but of course, a rigorous proof is needed. Indeed, there is:
- [Kulikowski's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KulikowskisTheorem.html) - gives explicit construction in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and generalizes to all higher dimensions:

*W. Sierpiński, ["Elementary Theory of Numbers: 2nd English Edition"](http://goo.gl/kI6UZ), page 386, the last paragraph:*

> T. Kulikowski [1] has proved that for any natural number *n* there 
>   exists a sphere (in the three-dimensional space), on the boundary of 
>   which there are precisely *n* points whose coordinates are integers. He 
>   generalized this theorem for spheres in spaces of an arbitrary $\ge 3$ 
>   dimension.

And similar problems related to interior points:

- [Steinhaus' theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleLatticePoints.html)
- [Browkin's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrowkinsTheorem.html)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this seems to be [Kulikowski's](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KulikowskisTheorem.html) theorem, see:

T. Kulikowski Sur l'existence d'une sphère passant par un nombre donné de points aux coordonnées entières. Enseignement Math. (2) 5 1959 89–90.

(the Mathworld link seems to mention the case $n=3$ only, but according to the MathScinet review, the theorem is proved in all dimensions).